I am getting an error creating a simple transaction. I am following Gimbalab tutorial
I have created several transaction on Nami but I have not been able to successfully process a transaction using the CLI.
cardano-cli conway transaction build 
--testnet-magic 1 
--tx-in $tx_in 
--tx-out $receiver+1000000 
--change-address $sender 
--out-file simple-tx.draft

Here is the error.
Size mismatch when decoding Record RecD.\nExpected 31, but found 30.
Here is the current cardano-node and cardano cli version
cardano-cli 8.20.3.0
cardano-node 8.9.0

I am using Demeter.
Here is the course I am following
https://www.andamio.io/course/ppbl2024/102/lesson/2
Does anyone know how I can overcome this error? I don't want to just move on from this lesson as it's things like this where you learn the most.

Update to 9! 8.12 shouldn't be used anymore.
